# two div aren't on the same level using css

Tags: html, css

I should have 2 lists on the same level, the data displayed in the 2 div  are from database and are variables from 1 to 10 line max

My problem is the second div is displaced down if the first div has more line 
If they have the same number of lines it’s ok

This is what I have now

[image]

this is my code:

```
<div style="width: 55%; display: inline-block; background-color: #aaffaa">
 <p style="
transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: 130px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background: gray;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 15px;
margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">List1: {{  form.varList}}
</p>

<p>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;  "> {{ form.var1 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;">  {{ form.var2 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var3 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; "> {{ form.var4 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var5 }}</span>

 </p>
   </div>



<div style=" width: 40%; display: inline-block;background-color: #00CC33;  ">
<p style="
transform: rotate(-90deg);
   width: 130px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   background: gray;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 15px;
                                    margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">Projects:{{.form.varprojects }}
 </p>

<p>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;"> {{ forme.var6 }} </span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var7}}</span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var8 }} </span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var9}}</span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var10 }} </span>

  </p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `max-width` instead of `width` in your div tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/7abx2wLe/
Use `vartical-align:top` for every div in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is because there is more content in the left block than in the right. Try using `vertical-align: top` on them, and if that fails go for `float:left;` instead of `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 55%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; background-color: #aaffaa">
 <p style="
transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: 130px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background: gray;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 15px;
margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">List1: {{  form.varList}}
</p>

<p>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;  "> {{ form.var1 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;">  {{ form.var2 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var3 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; "> {{ form.var4 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var5 }}</span>

 </p>
   </div>



<div style=" width: 40%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; background-color: #00CC33;  ">
<p style="
transform: rotate(-90deg);
   width: 130px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   background: gray;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 15px;
                                    margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">Projects:{{.form.varprojects }}
 </p>

<p>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;"> {{ forme.var6 }} </span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var7}}</span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var8 }} </span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var9}}</span>
          <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var10 }} </span>

  </p>
   </div>
```

Just set `vertical-align:top` on your `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Will work like, however if you would like the two divs to always be the same height you can wrap your whole code in a display:flex;

like:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
<div style="width: 55%; display: inline-block; background-color: #aaffaa">
    <p style="
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        width: 130px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
        background: gray;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">  List1: {{  form.varList}}
    </p>

    <p>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;  "> {{ form.var1 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px;">  {{ form.var2 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var3 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; "> {{ form.var4 }}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 90px; ">  {{ form.var5 }}</span>
    </p>
</div>



<div style=" width: 40%; display: inline-block;background-color: #00CC33;  ">
    <p style="
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        width: 130px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
        background: gray;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        margin: 40px 0 0 -40px">   Projects:{{.form.varprojects }}
    </p>

    <p>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;"> {{ forme.var6 }} </span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var7}}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var8 }} </span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var9}}</span>
        <span style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">  {{ form.var10 }} </span>
    </p>
</div>
```